# CSS Bottom not working correctly

Tags: css, position

I have this sidebar that i'm trying to move to the bottom for mobile view devices. However, this isn't working correctly and instead is putting the sidebar at the top of the page. Could anyone help?

```
<div id="checkoutForm">

*some stuff*

<div id="rightMenu">
<div id="checkoutCart" class="rightMenu__box"> 
*some more stuff*
</div>
</div>

</div>


#rightMenu {
    @media#{$medium-up} {
        float: right;
        width: auto;
        height: 0px;    
    }

    @media#{$small-only} {
        width: auto;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}

#checkoutForm {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;

    *some stuff*
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your "some stuff" in #checkoutForm are floating elements causing #checkoutForm not to force a size and subsequently having height 0px and looking like its rendering your absolute positioned element on the top.

Make sure this is not the case, a tried and tested technique to address that problem would be to use [clearfix](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods/).

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
  zoom: 1; /* ie 6/7 */
}


<div id="checkoutForm" class="clearfix">

*some stuff*

<div id="rightMenu">
<div id="checkoutCart" class="rightMenu__box"> 
*some more stuff*
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I added that and now it's to the point where it's getting to the bottom of the page but is hiding behind elements (text boxes) and not at the bottom bottom of the page..

Comment: If you can whip up a fiddle, I might be able to take a look.